# jQuery mouseup() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is something simple that I am missing but I'm at a loss.

I have this block of jQuery:

```
jQuery("span.frm_inline_total").digits();
  jQuery(".frm_input_group").on("blur", "input", function () {
    jQuery("span.frm_inline_total").digits();
  });

  jQuery(".frm_range_container input").mouseup(function () {
    jQuery("span.frm_inline_total").digits();
    console.log("mouse up");
  });
  jQuery(".frm_range_container input").mousedown(function () {
    jQuery("span.frm_inline_total").digits();
    console.log("mouse down");
  });
```

That calls a function to place commas in some field numbers. I don't think it's relevant, but here is the function:

```
 jQuery.fn.digits = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      jQuery(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
    })
  }
```

My issue is this. Everything works except when I try to call digits() using mouseup(). It logs the mouseup() event with 'console.log', and the mousedown() event correctly works, but no mouseup(). ...alert("mouse up") works, just not 'digits'.

For what it's worth, I'm placing this event on a built-in slider in a drag-and-drop website I am editing. My "development" is limited to client side code. There is already an event on it to retrieve the new values that I thought might be interfering, but then I don't understand why it would fire logs or alerts.

Comment: You are using ```jQuery``` to define jQuery but you are also using ```$``` in the digits function ```$(this).text().replace(...)```, maybe that's the issue? Does it log any errors?

Comment: I made it all $, sorry. Still no dice. My temporary solution was to add a delay <code>$(".frm_range_container input").change(function(){
       setTimeout(function() {
      $("span.frm_inline_total").digits();
           }, 20);
   });</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your HTML structure is something like this:

```
  <div class="frm_range_container">
    <div class="frm_input_group">
      <span class="frm_inline_total">Value to replace</span>
      <input value="Click me"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the rest of your code works, changing the code like below should produce desired output.

```js
// added logs to check in console, digits function is the same
$.fn.digits = function () {
    console.log('digits'); // test to see if reaches digits() function
    return this.each(function () {
      // this should be the correct element.
      $(this).text(
          $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
      );
  })
}

$(".frm_range_container input").on('mouseup mousedown', function (e) {
   console.log(e.type);
   $("span.frm_inline_total").digits();
});
```

If you want to only target `span.frm_inline_total` contained in each `frm_range_container`, you can use `$("span.frm_inline_total", this).digits();` for that